# C# foreach loop is only displaying 2 results within the entire json file

Tags: c#, json, datagridview

I need every players first and last name in JSON file to populate within in a datagridview. Everything is working fine except I am only getting 2 players in the dgv. Both players are  after the expected portion of the json, so the only 2 players that are showing for me are "Marcus Smart" and "Cedi Osman".

CODE:

```
    public void StartingLineups()
    {
        upass.upass up = new upass.upass();
        string address3 = "https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nba/2017-2018-regular/game_startinglineup.json?gameid=" + dateTimePicker1.Text + comboBox2.Text;

        var w3 = new WebClient();
        w3.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        w3.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(up.username, up.password);
        var result3 = w3.DownloadString(address3);

        var obj3 = JObject.Parse(result3);


        dt.Columns.Add("Projected Lineup", typeof(string));
        StartingLineup.startinglineup sl = new StartingLineup.startinglineup();


        foreach (JObject child in obj3["gamestartinglineup"]["teamLineup"])

        {

            sl.expected = child["expected"]["starter"][0]["player"]["FirstName"].ToString()  +  " " +  child["expected"]["starter"][0]["player"]["LastName"].ToString();
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            row["Projected Lineup"] = sl.expected;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

        }

    }
```

JSON:

```
{
      "gamestartinglineup": {
        "lastUpdatedOn": "2017-10-17 12:56:32 PM",
        "game": {
          "id": "42070",
          "date": "2017-10-17",
          "time": "8:00PM",
          "awayTeam": {
            "ID": "82",
            "City": "Boston",
            "Name": "Celtics",
            "Abbreviation": "BOS"
          },
          "homeTeam": {
            "ID": "86",
            "City": "Cleveland",
            "Name": "Cavaliers",
            "Abbreviation": "CLE"
          },
          "location": "Quicken Loans Arena"
        },
        "teamLineup": [
          {
            "team": {
              "ID": "82",
              "City": "Boston",
              "Name": "Celtics",
              "Abbreviation": "BOS"
            },
            "expected": {
              "starter": [
                {
                  "position": "Bench8",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9102",
                    "LastName": "Smart",
                    "FirstName": "Marcus",
                    "JerseyNumber": "36",
                    "Position": "PG"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Starter1",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9506",
                    "LastName": "Hayward",
                    "FirstName": "Gordon",
                    "JerseyNumber": "20",
                    "Position": "SF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Starter2",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "10090",
                    "LastName": "Brown",
                    "FirstName": "Jaylen",
                    "JerseyNumber": "7",
                    "Position": "SF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Starter5",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9082",
                    "LastName": "Horford",
                    "FirstName": "Al",
                    "JerseyNumber": "15",
                    "Position": "C"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Starter3",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9157",
                    "LastName": "Irving",
                    "FirstName": "Kyrie",
                    "JerseyNumber": "11",
                    "Position": "PG"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Starter4",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "13730",
                    "LastName": "Tatum",
                    "FirstName": "Jayson",
                    "JerseyNumber": "0",
                    "Position": "F"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench1",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "13775",
                    "LastName": "Ojeleye",
                    "FirstName": "Semi",
                    "JerseyNumber": "37",
                    "Position": "PF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench2",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "13778",
                    "LastName": "Yabusele",
                    "FirstName": "Guerschon",
                    "JerseyNumber": "30",
                    "Position": "PF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench3",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "13770",
                    "LastName": "Nader",
                    "FirstName": "Abdel",
                    "JerseyNumber": "28",
                    "Position": "SF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench4",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9105",
                    "LastName": "Rozier",
                    "FirstName": "Terry",
                    "JerseyNumber": "12",
                    "Position": "PG"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench5",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9211",
                    "LastName": "Baynes",
                    "FirstName": "Aron",
                    "JerseyNumber": "12",
                    "Position": "C"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench6",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9120",
                    "LastName": "Larkin",
                    "FirstName": "Shane",
                    "JerseyNumber": "8",
                    "Position": "PG"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench7",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "13777",
                    "LastName": "Theis",
                    "FirstName": "Daniel",
                    "JerseyNumber": "27",
                    "Position": "PF"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "actual": null
          },
          {
            "team": {
              "ID": "86",
              "City": "Cleveland",
              "Name": "Cavaliers",
              "Abbreviation": "CLE"
            },
            "expected": {
              "starter": [
                {
                  "position": "Bench8",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "13780",
                    "LastName": "Osman",
                    "FirstName": "Cedi",
                    "JerseyNumber": "16",
                    "Position": "SF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Starter1",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9315",
                    "LastName": "Wade",
                    "FirstName": "Dwyane",
                    "JerseyNumber": "9",
                    "Position": "SG"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Starter2",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9158",
                    "LastName": "James",
                    "FirstName": "LeBron",
                    "JerseyNumber": "23",
                    "Position": "SF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Starter5",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9161",
                    "LastName": "Love",
                    "FirstName": "Kevin",
                    "JerseyNumber": "0",
                    "Position": "PF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Starter3",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9142",
                    "LastName": "Rose",
                    "FirstName": "Derrick",
                    "JerseyNumber": "1",
                    "Position": "PG"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Starter4",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9107",
                    "LastName": "Crowder",
                    "FirstName": "Jae",
                    "JerseyNumber": "99",
                    "Position": "SF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench1",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9162",
                    "LastName": "Shumpert",
                    "FirstName": "Iman",
                    "JerseyNumber": "4",
                    "Position": "SG"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench2",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9169",
                    "LastName": "Thompson",
                    "FirstName": "Tristan",
                    "JerseyNumber": "13",
                    "Position": "PF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench3",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9167",
                    "LastName": "Smith",
                    "FirstName": "J.R.",
                    "JerseyNumber": "5",
                    "Position": "SG"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench4",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9089",
                    "LastName": "Korver",
                    "FirstName": "Kyle",
                    "JerseyNumber": "26",
                    "Position": "SG"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench5",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9271",
                    "LastName": "Green",
                    "FirstName": "Jeff",
                    "JerseyNumber": "32",
                    "Position": "SF"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench6",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9159",
                    "LastName": "Frye",
                    "FirstName": "Channing",
                    "JerseyNumber": "9",
                    "Position": "C"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "position": "Bench7",
                  "player": {
                    "ID": "9370",
                    "LastName": "Calderon",
                    "FirstName": "Jose",
                    "JerseyNumber": "29",
                    "Position": "PG"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "actual": null
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your loop only loops the two teams, and you take the first player from each team. You need to add a second loop inside the first to loop the players.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop on the timelineup element is not enough to list of the players in your team. You need an inner loop

```
foreach (JObject child in obj3["gamestartinglineup"]["teamLineup"])
{
    foreach (JObject sub in child["expected"]["starter"])
    {
        var expected = sub["player"]["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + sub["player"]["LastName"].ToString();
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Projected Lineup"] = expected;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Also do not assign the datasource for the gridview inside the loop but only when you finish to read everything

Answer (score 2):

You are using your foreach in a wrong place

```
    foreach (JObject child in obj3["gamestartinglineup"]["teamLineup"])
```

in this part of code, the loop consist of only 2 items!

[image: have a look here]

and the items  "Marcus Smart" and "Cedi Osman" are the first player of each

[image: have a look here]

Correct your foreach loop to fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

Your foreach loop is looping through the team line-up for the game line-up. There are only two teams in that lineup.  And you then grab only the first player out of each team.  The relevant lines of code are

```
foreach (JObject child in obj3["gamestartinglineup"]["teamLineup"])
{
        sl.expected = child["expected"]["starter"][0]["player"]["FirstName"].ToString()  +  " " +  child["expected"]["starter"][0]["player"]["LastName"].ToString();
```

the foreach is looping through the children of "teamlineup", and there are only two children, the two teams.

the `child["extected"]["starter"][0]["player"]` designation just gives you the first starter player for each of those two teams.

If you want to get all the starter players for each team, you will have to add a second foreach loop inside the first one, something like this...

```
foreach (JObject child in obj3["gamestartinglineup"]["teamLineup"])
{
    foreach (JObject player in child["expected"]["starter"]) 
    {
```